# How to change DevExpress DockPanel TabText while dock and undock

Tags: winforms, devexpress

While dock and undock ..I am having problem in "TabText" I have 5 panels while dock to left I want to show its name and undock from it .it will go to bottom of the form ...

My problem is while it goes to bottom I am setting `TabText` to `" "` .. But while all tabs are docking in bottom for fraction of a second names are showing up in it... I used `VisibilityChangedEventArgs` events to set `TabText` to `" "`

I need a solution that while docking to bottom name won't show up even for a fraction of a second

Comment: Is there any special property can be set for TabText as " " on Collapse State.. @ roken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem .. Here is the Code Which can be called before VisibilityChangedEventArgs for DevExpress Dock pannel

```
         protected override void UpdateRootPanels()
    {
        DockWindow objWindow = null;
        base.UpdateRootPanels();
        try
        {
            this.BeginUpdate();
            if (this.ActivePanel != null && this.ActivePanel.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int iCount = 0; iCount < this.ActivePanel.Count; iCount++)
                {
                    if (ActivePanel[iCount].Visibility == DockVisibility.Visible)
                    {
                        objWindow = GetDockWindowByName(ActivePanel[iCount].Name);
                        if ((objWindow.DockState == DockWindowDockStateConstants.Collapsed && this.PanelActivationList[1].Dock == DockingStyle.Fill)
                            || (objWindow.DockState == DockWindowDockStateConstants.Collapsed && this.PanelActivationList[1].Dock == DockingStyle.Right))
                        {
                            this.ActivePanel[iCount].TabText = " ";
                        }
                        //.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { this.ActivePanel[iCount].TabText = " "; }, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            this.EndUpdate();
        }
    }
```